# How do I update a sheet with the names of all sheets in a spreadsheet and value of a certain cell from each sheet to column B of this sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet to manage my clients. I fill a form and the responses are recorded in a mastersheet from where individual sheets for all clients get populated using script. Now I have another sheet where there is a list of all clients in column A and I want to copy value of h32 from each clients' individual sheet to this list sheet using a script and paste it in the column B next to the clients' name. I also need it to update the value of column b if it changes in the clients' sheet. I need it to ignore the other sheets with specific names like 'Outward' , 'Inward' and 'Payment Details' Sample spreadsheet attached.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NjWn_6ZfmkRLAJLf0zeBhuKlEP7vWRxOPCyFnRtTeVg/edit?usp=sharing

Do not know where to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't need script for this. Put this in 'List' B2 and copy down.

```
=iferror(INDIRECT(""&A2&"!$H$32"),"")
```

Comment: How do I automate this to add the same formula to whenever a new row is created?

Comment: Put =indirect("Clientsheet!B3:B") in List A2 and the answer formula in B2. You will still have to copy dow the formula in B2 (drag it down) it will be blank if A is blank. New entries in Clientsheet will be added and if H32 has data it will show in List.

Comment: Perfect. Works like a charm! Been fiddling with script for too long. Thank you so much @Ed.